# iOS app maximum iOS version support

Tags: iphone, ios

I have developed my app in `Xcode 4.1` and iOS SDK version(Base SDK Version) is  `iOS 4.3` So, will this app run on iPhone with `iOS 5` and/or `iOS 6` or not?

I think the app can be run on a higher version of the OS than the `Deployment Target`. Is this right? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your app will run on anything that is iOS 4.3 or newer. That is, assuming you aren't using any depreciated methods that are removed from a future iOS release. You can check if things have been depreciated/removed through the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter with which Xcode you build your app, the base SDK signifies the lowest system your app is supporting.

You app can and will run on newer systems.

If you want to make an update to your app, you'll need to pay attention to depreciated methods for the newer systems or you will get rejected and won't be able to update in the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will for sure run in higher versions than Deployment Target.
However, is always recommended to run also in newer versions as they are released, to check that every API used is still running fine (specially if they were deprecated).